# Are packages the only way to return data from an Oracle db?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I've mostly worked with SQL Server so far and now I'm moving to Oracle for a new project.

I'm trying to create a proc that will return data to a .net app. The only way I got this to work is by using packages like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE GetAllDepartments AS
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE p_GetAllDepartments
(
    cur_Result OUT T_CURSOR
);
END GetAllDepartments;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GetAllDepartments AS
PROCEDURE p_GetAllDepartments
(
    cur_Result OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_Result FOR
    SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS;

END p_GetAllDepartments;
END GetAllDepartments;
```

Is this the only way to go with Oracle?, can't I just create the proc and call that directly? Thanks

Comment: It is definitely possible to have just a stored procedure without a package and call it from a .net app. Do you get an execption when you try to execute such a procedure or just no result is returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a supported version of Oracle, you should be able to do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_all_departments( p_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_result
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM departments;
END get_all_departments;
```

That said, you are normally better off from an organization standpoint using packages to collect procedures that do related things.  In your case, for example, it would generally make sense to have a package that had all the procedures that dealt with departments (i.e. `create_department`, `delete_department`, etc.).

And from a general stylistic standpoint, it is more common in Oracle to create a view that implements whatever logic you would put in the stored procedure and to query that view rather than creating a stored procedure that just does a query.

Comment: it worked, that SYS_REFCURSOR data type is what I was missing, do you know why REFCURSOR doesnt work in this case?.. it seems I can use a refcursor param when invoking this proc, weird..

Comment: @Pablote - What do you mean by "REFCURSOR doesn't work"?  You could certainly create a package that defined a weakly typed REF CURSOR and then create a standalone procedure that uses that weakly typed REF CURSOR as an output parameter.  You can't define your own weakly typed REF CURSOR in a procedure and then use it as an OUT parameter because the declaration of the weakly typed cursor would be before the declaration of the OUT parameter and would not be visible outside of the scope of the procedure.  The use of the package simply allows you to declare the cursor before the procedure.

Comment: I can call the proc in your response with this code: [variable mycur REFCURSOR; exec get_all_departments(:mycur); print mycur;] ... but I can't use that same REFCURSOR in the proc declaration, I just found about SYS_REFCURSOR thanks to you.. what you say about the type declaration was my initial doubt about needing packages for procs with an OUT cursor param, thanks

Comment: @Pablote - Ah, OK.  `variable mycur REFCURSOR` is SQL*Plus syntax-- it creates a SQL*Plus substitution variable.  It is not PL/SQL syntax so it cannot be used in a PL/SQL block.  It is restricted to SQL*Plus and whatever client tools happen to implement the SQL*Plus syntax for declaring variables in the client environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without a package, e.g. by creating a function that returns result sets.

Those functions can be used like tables, e.g.: `SELECT * FROM my_function()`

This is especially efficient with pipelined function because the result is not buffered on the server but sent row by row to the client:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#i1008519

But the basic technique is still the same i.e. you have to define a type that is used for the return type of the function. You cannot have it return an "anonymous" result set like in PostgreSQL or SQL Server.